# Monodroid Project compiles successfully but errors afterwards

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xamarin.android

In my VS2010 solution I have several Monodroid Project, which are referencing each other (no circles).

The compilation finishes successfully, but after the compilation many errors happen (all of them not found types and methods). These errors disappear temporarily at the time when I remove the regarding reference and add it again.

I made this solution for debugging purposes, because in the original solution, I have only one monodroid Project, and there I'm referencing .Net assemblys. In the original solution I don't have any errors, but the debugging possibilities are bad. The c# files are only linked into the projects, not physically added.

Could this be an monodroid/VS issue?

Example Errors are:

> The type or namespace name 'Common' does not exist in the namespace 'Festo' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

The problem is that this Namespace does exist, but in an referenced Android assembly.The OnlineCompiler doesn't recognise it?

> The best overloaded method match for 'Festo.EditorSDK.Translation.TranslationTable.Translate(string, Festo.EditorSDK.Data.Variable)' has some invalid argumens

But there is a function that accepts these types and numbers of arguments, but as before, in an referenced Android assembly.

If I compile my solution explicitely through the button "Rebuild Solution", the compilation is successful. It's really strange!

Comment: You need to post the specific errors please.

Comment: I've seen this a few times since installing VS2012 on the same machine. If you have a reproducible sample, please log it with Xamarin for investigation - http://bugzilla.xamarin.com